# How to Implement google and Facebook url handling in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am looking to implement Google as well as Facebook Log-in  functionality.Both of them have a url handling method that is supposed to in appDelegate.Now how do I distinguish between the two  request here.

The Facebook method is like this.

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {

          // Call FBAppCall's handleOpenURL:sourceApplication to handle Facebook app responses
             BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

          // You can add your app-specific url handling code here if needed

              return wasHandled;
   }
```

Whereas Google's method looks like this :

```
 - (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application
        openURL: (NSURL *)url
   sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation: (id)annotation {
         return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
               sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                  annotation:annotation];
 }
```

Comment: You can distinguish it by checking the sourceApplication or url. If the  source application is Facebook then handle it according to Facebook or if it is Google then handle it to that way similarly for any thing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just **or** it

```
 return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
               sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                  annotation:annotation] || [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
```

Comment: `[GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation]` would cause crash here if you are logging in with Facebook. Reversing the order around `||` would work fine though.